# Why were Loki and Bartleby afraid of the Apostle in the film Dogma?

Tags: plot-explanation, dogma

In the train when they are talking to Bethany and they see the Apostle they panic and jump up, taking Bethany hostage.

Why?  What could he have done?  There were two of them, logically they could have overpowered him if he tried anything physical and he did not seem to have anything else to offer.

Why was there a problem?

Answer (score 5):

There's one main reason it could be a problem:

1. **The Apostle is immortal**
   As we can tell from his entrance when he falls out of the sky onto a tarmac road uninjured (except for a migraine). Then the following exchange takes place which further proves it (emphasis mine):

   > **Bethany**: You know, it's been a while since physics but I would think the impact with which you hit the asphalt would have liquified you.
   >
   > **Rufus**: Death is a worry of the living. **The dead, like myself, only worry about decay and necrophiliacs**.
   >
   > **Jay**: Told you he was the undead.
   >
   > **Rufus**: Not the undead. The dead. I died. Christ told me the secret to resurrection once. We were at this wedding in Canaan. And I got drunk and forgot it.

   Furthermore, at the end of the film he didn't have to shield his ears from the voice of God when she killed Bartleby (instead he helped Serendipity to cover Jay's ears). This means there's nothing they could do to him except restrain him (assuming he has no ability to return to heaven, which he may well).
2. **Bartleby and Loki are not immortal**
   Their returning to heaven requires them to cut off their wings which makes them mortal, as Bartleby says near the start of the film:

   > If we cut off our wings and transubstantiate to complete human form, we become mortal.

   So all it would take is a sword to kill them both (Or an Uzi, like Jay uses later).

Comment: That's a good answer, and I'd have to watch the movie again to be sure of the details, but there does seem to be an inconsistency.   Bartleby and Loki seemed to have no trouble overpowering the "goodguys" later in the movie.

Answer (score 4):

They panicked because they *knew* that he was Rufus (the Apostle), and that the Apostle was traveling with the last scion to stop them from traveling through the altar.

Comment: But so what? What was he going to do? Why didn't they just throw him off the train? Knife him? Cut his eyes out etc?